# Given a distance, and velocity as a function of time, how do I find the time taken to travel the distance?

Tags: kinematics, time, velocity, calculus, distance

Given the velocity of a particle as a function of time V(t), and a distance between two points on a straight line (from point A to point B), I would like to find the time it will take the particle to travel this distance.

To solve this, I first obtain velocity as a function of position V(x). I do this by integrating V(t) to obtain X(t), isolating the t variable in terms of X, and then in V(t) replacing t with the obtained expression containing X. This gives me V(x).

So I have developed the following formula for total time T to travel the distance, but haven't been able to validate online if it is correct (it seems to be correct, judging by some examples I did):

T = [Integral from A to B] of [1 / V(x)] dx

Please let me know if I have any mistakes here.

Comment: it would be likely easier to integrate $\int v(t) dt=\Delta x$, and find T from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, it would have been easier to compute $\int_0^T v(t)dt=\Delta x$ and isolate T from here. However your reasoning is valid and should give you the same answer.